# Array displaying images, need to make another method that takes a paramter NUM

Tags: java, arrays, parameters

I explained that horridly in the title, and I apologize, am very new to java and don't quite understand some of it yet.

Anyway,

My cat animation runs to the middle of the screen, scratches twice, then continues to run to the end, is there anyway to write a method that will take an INT NUM and make the cat scratch x amount of times? Not sure how to go about doing this.

Any help would be great,

Here is my current code

```
/** Run the animation. */
public void nekoRun() {
    moveIn();
    scratch();
    //scratch2(5);
    moveOut();
}

/* Move Neko to the centre of the panel. */
private void moveIn() {
    for (int i = 0; i < getWidth()/2; i+=10) {
        xPos = i;
        // swap images
        if (currentImage == nekoPics[0]) 
            currentImage = nekoPics[1];
        else 
            currentImage = nekoPics[0];
        repaint();
        pause(150);
    }   
}
private void scratch() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)  {


        // Swap images.
        currentImageIndex = nextImageList[currentImageIndex];
        currentImage = nekoPics[currentImageIndex];


            repaint();
            pause(150);
        }
}

private void moveOut() {
    for (int i = xPos; i < getWidth(); i+=10) {
        xPos = i;
        // swap images
        if (currentImage == nekoPics[0]) 
            currentImage = nekoPics[1];

        else 
            currentImage = nekoPics[0];
        repaint();
        pause(150);
    }   
}
```

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < N_SCRATCH; i++) { scratch(); }` ?

Comment: @assylias i'm not really following this comment that well, any chance you could explain a bit more ?

Comment: You could introduce a loop in the nekoRun method, and pass the number of scratch as an argument of that method.